# Why does my code slow down when i replace arrays with stl vectors, in c++, are arrays more faster than vectors?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, heap-memory, stdvector

Below is the code I used for comparing:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std;
            
bool existHelperArrayVersion(string &word, int i, int u_i, int u_j, vector<vector<char>>& Board)
{
    if(i>=word.length())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        bool answer  = false;      
        if(Board[u_i][u_j] == word[i])
        {
            char temp             = Board[u_i][u_j];
            Board[u_i][u_j]       = '?';
            int row_len           = Board.size();  
            int col_len           = Board[0].size();

            // Uses Array
            int row_offset[4]={0,  0, 1, -1};
            int col_offset[4]={1, -1, 0,  0};
            
            for(int k=0; k<4; k++)
            {
                int v_i = u_i + row_offset[k];
                int v_j = u_j + col_offset[k];
                
                if( !(0 >v_i || v_i >= row_len || 0>v_j || v_j >= col_len)  && (Board[v_i][v_j] != '?'))
                    answer |= existHelperArrayVersion(word, i+1, v_i, v_j, Board);
            }
               
            if(i+1 == word.length())
                answer |= true;
            Board[u_i][u_j] = temp;
        }
        return answer;
    }
}

bool existHelperVectorVersion(string &word, int i, int u_i, int u_j, vector<vector<char>>& Board)
{
    if(i>=word.length())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        bool answer  = false;
        if(Board[u_i][u_j] == word[i])
        {
            char temp             = Board[u_i][u_j];
            Board[u_i][u_j]       = '?';
            int row_len           = Board.size();  
            int col_len           = Board[0].size();

            //Uses Vectors
            vector<int> row_offset = {0,  0, 1, -1};
            vector<int> col_offset = {1, -1, 0,  0};
            
            for(int k=0; k<4; k++)
            {
                int v_i = u_i + row_offset[k];
                int v_j = u_j + col_offset[k];
                
                if( !(0 >v_i || v_i >= row_len || 0>v_j || v_j >= col_len)  && (Board[v_i][v_j] != '?'))
                    answer |= existHelperVectorVersion(word, i+1, v_i, v_j, Board);
            }
               
            if(i+1 == word.length())
                answer |= true;
            Board[u_i][u_j] = temp;
        }
        return answer;
    }
}

bool exist(vector<vector<char>>& board, string word, int option) 
{
    if(option == 0)
        cout << "----ARRAY------\n";
    else if(option == 1)
        cout << "---VECTOR-----\n";
        
    bool answer   = false;
    for(int i=0; i<board.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<board[i].size(); j++)
        {
            if(option == 0)
                answer |= existHelperArrayVersion( word, 0, i, j, board);
            else if(option == 1)
                answer |= existHelperVectorVersion( word, 0, i, j, board);
                
            if(answer)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    
    string word                 =   "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAB";
    vector<vector<char>> board  =   {{'A','A','A','A','A','A'},
                                     {'A','A','A','A','A','A'},
                                     {'A','A','A','A','A','A'},
                                     {'A','A','A','A','A','A'},
                                     {'A','A','A','A','A','A'},
                                     {'A','A','A','A','A','A'}};

    auto start    = high_resolution_clock::now();
    bool answer   = exist(board, word, 0);
    auto stop     = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);
    cout << "Time taken when Using C-style Array : " << duration.count() << " microseconds" << endl;
    
    start         = high_resolution_clock::now();
    answer        = exist(board, word, 1);
    stop          = high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration      = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);
    cout << "Time taken when Using STL vector    : " << duration.count() << " microseconds" << endl;
    
}
```

output

```
----ARRAY------
Time taken when Using C-style Array : 112931 microseconds
---VECTOR-----
Time taken when Using STL vector    : 330641 microseconds
```

As you can see the array version of my function performs on average 3 times faster than that of its Vector version. (I ran it multiple times and got similar results)

Question: 
Are vectors really that slow compared to arrays? 
I thought their performance was supposed to be on par. 
This is the URL I run it on an online environment http://cpp.sh/2ubur

Comment: How did you compile the code? Make sure to enable optimizations. Measuring unoptimized builds is not meaningful.

Comment: You are comparing `int[4]` with `std::vector<int>`. This is not a good use case for `std::vector` since the size is constant. A better comparison would be `int[4]` with `std::array<int, 4>` or comparing `std::vector<int>` with a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I run it on an online ide this is the link cpp.sh/6x22b

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux but i thought vectors were sopposed to be on par with arrays right?

Comment: The posted link doesn't work for me. Though I'll guess it runs on gcc, so the -O3 flag should enable optimizations.

Comment: `std::vector` solves the problem for when an array's size has to change dynamically. They are not interchangeable, they do different things. `std::vector` will have comparable performance to an array *if you need to frequently change the array's size*. If you know the size at compile time use `std::array` which is a C++ wrapper around C arrays.

Comment: You're instanciating a new vector here `vector<int> row_offset = {0,  0, 1, -1};` and here `vector<int> col_offset = {1, -1, 0,  0};`. As a vector uses dynamic memory allocation it is of course much slower than allocating a local raw array which is more or less done in zero time.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I updated the link  http://cpp.sh/6x22b

Comment: `std::vector` is not and can not be on par with plain arrays or `std::array`. The simple reason is that it needs some kind of indirection (i.e. pointers) in order to accomodate dynamic size changes. That in turn means that in order to get at element #3 using the address of the vector, you first read the address of the first element from the vector and then advance by three elements. For arrays, the array's address is the address of the first element.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I see now thanks. (I was under the impression one was a replacement for the other)

Comment: Just for completeness: Any time you think about `new T[count]`, you should instead think about `vector<T>`, that's probably what you read (in some form) and misinterpreted here.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt this is such a relevant analogy. It does make sense now on a whole new level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
        vector<int> row_offset = {0,  0, 1, -1};
        vector<int> col_offset = {1, -1, 0,  0};
```

this causes 2 heap allocations of data (almost) every time the function is called.

```
        int row_offset[4]={0,  0, 1, -1};
        int col_offset[4]={1, -1, 0,  0};
```

this does not cause 2 heap allocations of data (almost) every time the function is called.

`std::vector<int> foo = {1,2,3}` is similar to `int* foo = new int[]{1,2,3}`, not `int foo[] = {1,2,3}` in creation costs.

```
std::array<int, 3> foo={1,2,3}
```

is the std library version of "fixed size buffer with data in it".  `std::vector` is a dynamically sized buffer.

[Here](http://cpp.sh/8m7xt) is a live example where I swapped `std::vector` for `std::array`, and changed the C-array version to dynamically create and destroy the arrays.  You'll notice the time swaps.

Comment: This makes soo much sense. thanks

Answer (score 4):

You create your vectors in your function, so each function invocation allocates their memory anew and destroys them at the end of the function. An array is instead constantly baked into your program.

Try moving your vectors out of your function, then both functions are equally fast: http://cpp.sh/53t2z

Answer (score 3):

If you replace:

```
  vector<int> row_offset = { 0,  0, 1, -1 };
  vector<int> col_offset = { 1, -1, 0,  0 };
```

with:

```
  static vector<int> row_offset; row_offset  = { 0,  0, 1, -1 };
  static vector<int> col_offset; col_offset = { 1, -1, 0,  0 };
```

the difference will be much less. With the second version the vectors won't be constructed from scratch each time.

**This is only for demonstration purposes, and it's not an example to follow.**

At any rate the best approach here is to replace `std::vector` with `std::array` since you have fixed sizes here.

BTW on http://cpp.sh the version with `std::array` even seems to be somewhat faster than the raw array version.

Comment: Make those vectors constant, I don't think they are modified. Also, make them `std::array`s, again because they are not modified. Just to elaborate on that: If you don't want to modify them and make them constant, the compiler will tell you if you accidentally modify them. Prefer compiler errors over linker errors over runtime errors over errors that only happen on your customer's system in the middle of the night. ;)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt this is just for demonstration. It's not an example to follow. I  have edited the answer to make that clear.